# Tkinter canvas scaling causing image to blur

Tags: python, tkinter, scale, tkinter-canvas

I've implemented a Tkinter canvas object with a zoom function, following another stack exchange post with some modification. The function is:

```
  def wheel(self, event):
      ''' Zoom with mouse wheel '''
      scale = 1.0
      if self.imscale > 6 and event.delta == 120:
        return
      # Respond to Linux (event.num) or Windows (event.delta) wheel event
      if event.delta == -120:
          scale        -= .5
          self.imscale -= .5
      if event.delta == 120:
          scale        += .5
          self.imscale += .5
      # Rescale all canvas objects
      x = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
      y = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
      self.canvas.scale('all', x, y, scale, scale)
      self.show_image()
      self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))

  def show_image(self):
      ''' Show image on the Canvas '''
      if self.imageid:
          self.canvas.delete(self.imageid)
          self.imageid = None
          self.canvas.imagetk = None  # delete previous image from the canvas
      width, height = self.image.size
      new_size = int(self.imscale * width), int(self.imscale * height)
      imagetk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image.resize(new_size))
      # Use self.text object to set proper coordinates
      self.imageid = self.canvas.create_image(self.canvas.coords(self.text),
                                              anchor='nw', image=imagetk)
      self.canvas.lower(self.imageid)  # set it into background
      self.canvas.imagetk = imagetk  # keep an extra reference to prevent garbage-collection
```

However, when using this scale function, the image in question blurs, despite being a pixel art image where blurring shouldn't? occur.

I've looked around and seen windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1) mentioned as a possible solution, but I added that to my script and nothing changed.

I've attached pictures of the blurry, tkinter-scaled image, and a "true" picture of the image zoomed in with MS paint.

Any help would be appreciated! I would ~prefer~ to not have to move off Tkinter, but if there's no other resolution possible I can.

[image: A picture of the "blurry" image]

[image: A picture of how the image should look (zoomed in microsoft paint)]

Comment: imagetk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image.resize(new_size), Image.ANTIALIAS)        try to use it and see if it becomes better

Comment: @AbhishekAggarwal Tried it-- doesn't seem to improve the blurriness at all.

Comment: @AbhishekAggarwal You led me down the right track though- see my posted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, answered my own question with the help of Abhishek Aggarwal in the comments! ANTIALIAS didn't work as a resampling filter, but I tried NEAREST and that completely solved it.

Thanks!